# UI-tinimcy textarea required

Tags: angularjs, tinymce

I want add validation to `ui-tinymce` `textarea` to check is body empty

```
<form id="SomeForm">
<textarea
 id="QuestionBody"
 name="questionBody"
 ng-model="vm.body"
 ui-tinymce="vm.tinymceOptions"
 required>
</textarea>
```

with next error message

```
<div ng-messages="SomeForm.questionBody.$error">
<label
for="QuestionBody"
class="error-text"
ng-message="required">
Error
</label>
</div>
```

And problem that if user click `Enter`, `required` doesn't see that body empty, because `ui-tinymce` add something like `<p>&nbsp</p>`.

Firstly I try add to config valid_elements property

```
valid_elements : '-#p'
```

but it delete all empty `p` elements.

`forced_root_block` also doesn't help

How can I add validation that makes form valid only if textarea has characters?

If it possible without jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are seeing is that the standard directives like validate just count characters so a simple (empty) HTML sample:

```
<p></p>
```

Would indeed show as 7 characters when in reality there is no "visible" content.

The easiest solution here is to build a custom directive and use jQuery's .text() function against the HTML. This removes all of the HTML tags and provides an approximation for the number of actual text characters in the editor.

The portion of the code in the directive that would do the work would be something like this:

```
var jStrippedString = jQuery(modelValue).text().trim();
return (maxlength < 0) || 
       ngModelCtrl.$isEmpty(jStrippedString) || 
       (jStrippedString.length <= maxlength);
```

I believe that you would want to create a custom Attribute directive that allows you to grab the model data for the editor and perform this validation yourself.

Comment: Don't need jQuery. `angular.element`has  `text()` method that does  same . Simple to create a new element and append the html string to it...then run `text()` on that new element